# Logic behind Recursive functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, return

I have the following recursive function below that returns the `k` to the `s` power of a certain integer.

However I do not understand how it works. The base class is 1 when `s` becomes 0.

How is it so that the returned value is actually `k^s` when `1` is returned? Since `1` is returned I would expect `powertoK(k, s)` to be `1` all the time.

Are there 2 memory addresses one holding 1 and the other as `k^s`?

```
def powertoK(k, s): 
    if s != 0:
        return k* powertoK(k,s-1)
    else:
        return 1
powertoK(3, 7)
```

Comment: You have to understand that one (recursive) call adds one level to the call stack and each `return` removes one level. Or in other words: there are as many calls as there are returns (unless there's an exception). And BTW: why is your function called differently than the call?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): ...    return k* power(k,s-1) , NameError: name 'power' is not defined`  please fix.

Comment: Your example boils down to `3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1`.  Does that help explain things?

Comment: "How is it so that the returned value is actually k^s when 1 is returned?" Well, k to the power 0 is 1, and we only `return 1` when s is equal to 0. In other cases - do you agree that one way to compute k to the power of s, is to compute k to the power of (s-1) and then multiply that result by k? For example, if I want to find the cube of a number, I could find the square of the number first and then multiply it again, right? Then, is that not **exactly what the code says**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to memory addresses. Look at the different calls that happen during the recursion. I'm using smaller numbers (`2³`) to keep it shorter:

```
powertok(2, 3)
= 2 * powertok(2, 2)
= 2 * 2 * powertok(2, 1)
= 2 * 2 * 2 * powertok(2, 0)
= 2 * 2 * 2 * 1
= 8
```

So only at the end the return value is `1` - but you are multiplying that with all the previous return values, because the initial call to `powertok(2, 3)` returns `2` multiplied by the return value of `powertok(2, 2)`, and so on, until it gets multiplied by the return value of `powertok(2, 0)` which is the hardcoded `1` (instead of calling `powertok` again).